# "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" cannot be loaded in-process on a 64-bit SQL Server

Tags: sql, ssis, ms-office

I can not find a solution for this error:

> The 32-bit OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" cannot be loaded in-process on a 64-bit SQL Server.

I found a lot of posts on the web but none work.

I am working with SQL server 2014 64 bits and office 2013

Code that generates the error:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                         'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;Database=C:\SSIS\Table_nm.xlsx', 
                         'SELECT * FROM [Table_nm$]');
```

Comment: Could you post the code that generates this error?

Comment: sure this is the code:
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;Database=C:\SSIS\Table_nm.xlsx',
    'SELECT * FROM [Table_nm$]');

Comment: Have you tried using the 64 bit driver [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)? There are [several references](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=microsoft.ace.oledb%2064%20bit) to it fixing similar problems.

Comment: thanks paqo gomez, Gracias paco eso corrigio el problema,

Comment: Excellente, un placer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As it turns out, you can get the 64-bit driver from here.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

After you download it, don't double-click it to install it, install it using the command prompt, which should be something like this:

```
"C:\Users\rshuell001\Downloads\AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe" /passive
```

The '`/passive`' is the key here because it prevents the installation from failing if you already have the 32-bit version installed (via 32-bit Office).

Comment: Do you know why installation of 64bit driver (with or w/o /passive key) would fail? The error message states just that. Running as admin or regular user, no difference.

Comment: In my case, just the "/passive" parameter was still causing an error, but I was able to make it work with AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe /quiet /passive