# Importing data from Excel into SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, excel, import-from-excel

I am currently using

- Office 2016 32-bit
- SQL Server 2016

Steps taken:

1. Installed `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provided in a post
2. Ran command

   ```
   SP_CONFIGURE 'show advanced options', 1; 

   RECONFIGURE;
   GO  
   SP_CONFIGURE 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1; 

   RECONFIGURE; 
   GO
   ```
3. Now I run this command:

   ```
   SELECT * 
   INTO #InertTable 
   FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                   'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Users\Samra\Documents\..\Supervisor Grandfathering.xls',  
                   'SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]')
   ```

But I get an error

> The 32-bit OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" cannot be loaded in-process on a 64-bit SQL Server.

I also tried:

1. right-clicking **database -> import**
2. Chose Microsoft Excel from Datasource
3. specified file name Excel
4. version -> Microsoft 2016

Now it says `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0` provider is not registered on local machine

I also went to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=54920 and downloaded it, and now when I run 64-bit version to install it says

> You cannot install the 64-bit version of Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 because you currently have 32-bit Office products installed. If you want to install 64-bit Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016, you will first need to remove the 32-bit installation of Office products....

For which i have to ask my admin and set it up later.
Isn't there an easy way around all this? I just need to import data from an excel into a table

Comment: If your file size is small, use online excel to SQL converter... [Sqlizer](https://sqlizer.io/#/)

Comment: Well after all this hassle we logged into the server where all configurations were correct instead of using my local machine. Now the task is done, but a solution for my local machine is only to uninstall 32-bit office and use 64-bit i guess?

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567548/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-cannot-be-loaded-in-process-on-a-64-bit-sql-server